# Git still tracking a file that I already deleted

Tags: git, github, version-control, push, commit

I am working with a large text file that exceeds the maximum allowable file size that git allows, so it's not allowing me to push my local commits to remote. I've tried creating a .gitignore file and adding the path of the file to it, but I still get the same problem.

I've also tried:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

As well as:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <path/to/file>
```

I've even deleted the file then re-commit and push:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

but git still thinks I'm trying to push the large text file. I'm stumped as to how I can un-track the file from git.

Answer (score 2):

Note : `git rm --cached` unstage only from the index, not from the repository.

The text file **has already been registered in a previous commit** in your repository. Even if you try to modify your repository with new commits, the old one is still there. Git will try to push it anyway.

So you need to edit this previous commit and remove the file registered in it. You have to rewrite the history of the commits : `git rebase -i specific-commit-id` will be your friend. At this point, you can use `git rm --cached` to remove the big text file in this commit. Then `git commit` to update it.

Comment: When I try to modify the latest commit with: git rebase -i spefic-commit-id, I get the following message:                                                                                                   
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.                                                                                      Do I have to modify all of the commits that contain that specific file?

Comment: You should `git stash` or `git commit` them; depending on what you want at the moment. With `git stash` it will save your last modifications and you can get them back with `git stash apply`.